# Calculate all values in the column and add it below as total sum

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to calculate all values in the column `C` and place it at the bottom on the same Column C as total sum.

I'm generating excel with data from database - some orders and their amount. Want to calculate the total amount.

My script is

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();    
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
    
$i = 1;
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, '#');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, 'Date');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, 'Amount');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i, '');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT  id, date, order_sum, SUM(order_sum) as totalSum FROM orders ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $order_sum, $totalSum );
    
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
        $i++;       
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $id);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, $date);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $order_sum);
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i,  '=SUM(C2:C'.($totalSum -1).')' );
}
$stmt->close();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=orders.xls');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');   
$file->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$file->save('php://output');
```

But got error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: Worksheet!D2 -> undefined variable '.'

Comment: Why are you using an Excel Formula...? You have a PHP Script that can calculate this sum.

Answer (score 3):

I have got it to work like this:

```
$column = "D";
$column_total = "C";
$row = $i+1;
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column_total.$row, 'Total: ');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$row , '=SUM(C3:C'.$i.')');
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution sorry I couldn't help you with my script.

Comment: But I don't have PHPExcel installed on the server I'm working on. It's not easy to test the script :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a PHP Excel Pro and don't have it available to me at the time of writing but this script should work I think

```
<?
$excel = new PHPExcel();    
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
    
$i = 1;
$generalSum = 0;

$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, '#');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, 'Date');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, 'Amount');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT  id, date, order_sum, SUM(order_sum) as totalSum FROM orders ");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $date, $order_sum, $totalSum );
    
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
  $i++;       
  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $id);
  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, $date);
  $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $order_sum);

  // Incrementation Sum
  $generalSum = bcadd($generalSum, $order_sum);
}

// Incrementation
$i++;    

// Display Bottom Line with Sum
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i,0);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i,0);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i,$generalSum);

$stmt->close();

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=orders.xls');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');   
$file->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
$file->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but got `Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string`

Comment: Because of the empty cell. When I remove them got `Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Invalid cell coordinate 112323` where `112323` is total sum actually. Seems like doesn't know where to put it.

Comment: I modify the script. I forgot parameter in setCellValue() on the bottom line

Comment: Thanks but another error `PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered`, here `$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i+1, '');` .. I guess for other below same

Comment: And if you use `$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i+1,0)` ....?

Comment: Still the same `A non-numeric value encountered` + I just saw that there is addition error as well `Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Invalid cell coordinate 1` and this one which points to the same line `PHPExcel_Worksheet->setCellValue(1, 0)`

Comment: I can get this one to work: `$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i, $generalSum);` but this adds the total sum next to the last C cell, I'm trying to put it below the last cell. For example last cell is `C:300`, the total amount should be on `C:301` not on `D:300`.

Comment: Yes I know it's what I use `'C'.$i` in bottom line. Do you test the last modification with incrementation of $i I put in the script before bottom line..?